# Using Supervisord to manage mongos process

Tags: mongodb, sharding, supervisord, autostart

**background**

I am trying to automate the restarting in case of crash or reboot for **mongos** process used in mongodb sharded setup.

**Case 1** : using direct command, with *mongod* user

*supervisord config*

```
[program:mongos_router]
command=/usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
user=mongod
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
```

**Result**

*supervisord log*

```
INFO spawned: 'mongos_router' with pid 19535
INFO exited: mongos_router (exit status 0; not expected)
INFO gave up: mongos_router entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

*mongodb log*

```
  2018-05-01T21:08:23.745+0000 I SHARDING [Balancer] balancer id: ip-address:27017 started
  2018-05-01T21:08:23.745+0000 E NETWORK  [mongosMain] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
  2018-05-01T21:08:23.745+0000 E NETWORK  [mongosMain]   addr already in use
  2018-05-01T21:08:23.745+0000 I -        [mongosMain] Invariant failure inShutdown() src/mongo/db/auth/user_cache_invalidator_job.cpp 114
  2018-05-01T21:08:23.745+0000 I -        [mongosMain] 

  ***aborting after invariant() failure


  2018-05-01T21:08:23.748+0000 F -        [mongosMain] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

Process is seen running. But if killed does not restart automatically.

**Case 2** : Using init script

here the slight change in the scenario is that some `ulimit` commands, creation of pid files is to be done as root and then the actual process should be started as `mongod` user.

*mongos script*

```
start()
{
  # Make sure the default pidfile directory exists
  if [ ! -d $PID_PATH ]; then
    install -d -m 0755 -o $MONGO_USER -g $MONGO_GROUP $PIDDIR

  fi

  # Make sure the pidfile does not exist
  if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
    echo "Error starting mongos. $PID_FILE exists."
    RETVAL=1
    return
  fi

  ulimit -f unlimited
  ulimit -t unlimited
  ulimit -v unlimited
  ulimit -n 64000
  ulimit -m unlimited
  ulimit -u 64000
  ulimit -l unlimited

  echo -n $"Starting mongos: "
  #daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" --pidfile $PID_FILE $MONGO_BIN $OPTIONS --pidfilepath=$PID_FILE
  #su $MONGO_USER -c "$MONGO_BIN -f $CONFIGFILE --pidfilepath=$PID_FILE  >> /home/mav/startup_log"
  su - mongod -c "/usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid"

  RETVAL=$?
  echo -n  "Return value : "$RETVAL
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $MONGO_LOCK_FILE
}
```

`daemon` comman represents original script, but daemonizing under the supervisord is not logical, so using command to run the process in foreground(?)

*supervisord config*

```
[program:mongos_router_script]
command=/etc/init.d/mongos start
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
```

**Result**

*supervisord log*

```
INFO spawned: 'mongos_router_script' with pid 20367     
INFO exited:  mongos_router_script (exit status 1; not expected)
INFO gave up: mongos_router_script entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

*mongodb log*

```
Nothing indicating error, normal logs
```

Process is seen running. But if killed does not restart automatically.

**Problem**

How to correctly configure script / no script option for running mongos under supervisord ?

**EDIT 1**

*Modified Command*

```
sudo su -c "/usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid" -s /bin/bash mongod`
```

This works if ran individually on command line as well as part of the script, but not with supervisord

**EDIT 2**

Added following option to config file for `mongos` to force it to run in the foreground

```
processManagement:
    fork: false # fork and run in background
```

Now command line and script properly run it in the foreground but supervisord fails to launch it. At the same time there are 3 processes show up when ran from command line or script

```
root   sudo su -c /usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid -s /bin/bash mongod
root   su -c /usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid -s /bin/bash mongod
mongod /usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
```

**EDIT 3**

With following `supervisord` config things are working fine. But I want to try and execute the script if possible to set `ulimit`

```
[program:mongos_router]
 command=/usr/bin/mongos -f /etc/mongos.conf --pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
 user=mongod
 autostart=true
 autorestart=true
 startretries=10
 numprocs=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mongos to run in the foreground set the following option

```
#how the process runs
processManagement:
    fork: false  # fork and run in background
```

with that and above `supervisord.conf` setting, `mongos` will be launched and under the `supervisord` control